# Select all items that do not have a match in another column

Tags: sql, oracle, comparison, aggregate-functions

I have this table

```
type     item     yield    section
-----------------------------------
CT1   |    A   |   25   |   M-2
CT1   |    A   |   35   |   M-1
CT2   |    A   |   70   |   M-1
CT2   |    A   |   30   |   M-2
CT2   |    A   |   20   |   M-3
CT1   |    B   |   40   |   M-2
CT1   |    B   |   15   |   M-1
CT2   |    B   |   25   |   M-1
CT2   |    B   |   25   |   M-2
```

First I need to sum all `yield` by `Item and Type` and divide it by each yield per row on my table. Second I need to know which `yield` is the same per `costtypcd, item and section` (I.E. `type` CT1 `item` A `section` M-1 has a yield of .58 (25+35=60 then 35/60 is .58) and `type` CT2 `item`. A `section` M-1 also has a yield of .58 so I don't want to select that item because it's a match).

So far I have this code that can only get the yield (already computed but can't figure out how to select only those `items` that do not have a match in `yield,item and section`

```
select type,item,yield, section
FROM(
Select type, item,
       Round(yield/Sum(yield) Over (Partition By type,item),2) As yield,section
From MyTable
Order By item
)
```

So my question is how can I get all items that only has a match in `yield` where they have the same `item,section and different type`?

In my table only `CT1 A M-1` AND `CT2 A M-1` is a match in yield so I'd like to select all the remaining items.

Expected Output:

```
type     item     section
--------------------------
CT1   |    A   |    M-2
CT2   |    A   |    M-2
CT2   |    A   |    M-3
CT1   |    B   |    M-2
CT1   |    B   |    M-1
CT2   |    B   |    M-1
CT2   |    B   |    M-2
```

I don't need to show the yield.

Comment: Please show your exact expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen done

Comment: Your sample calculation doesn't seem to add up with the actual data.

Comment: How do you get 0.58 as the yield ("percentage" yield is more correct) for CT2 A M-1? it's 70/100, which is 0.7, no?

Comment: sorry had a typo with CT 2 A M-03 was 0 now its 20 so its 70/120 = .58 @mathguy

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen fixed my data had a typo check above comment

Answer (score 0):

```
with
     inputs ( type, item, yield, section ) as (
       select 'CT1', 'A', 25, 'M-2' from dual union all
       select 'CT1', 'A', 35, 'M-1' from dual union all
       select 'CT2', 'A', 70, 'M-1' from dual union all
       select 'CT2', 'A', 30, 'M-2' from dual union all
       select 'CT2', 'A', 20, 'M-3' from dual union all
       select 'CT1', 'B', 40, 'M-2' from dual union all
       select 'CT1', 'B', 15, 'M-1' from dual union all
       select 'CT2', 'B', 25, 'M-1' from dual union all
       select 'CT2', 'B', 25, 'M-2' from dual
     ),
     prep ( type, item, yield, section, pct ) as (
       select type, item, yield, section,
              yield / sum(yield) over (partition by type, item)
       from   inputs
     ),
     final ( type, item, yield, section, pct, ct ) as (
       select type, item, yield, section, pct, 
              count(distinct type) over (partition by item, section, pct)
       from   prep
     )
select type, item, section
from   final
where  ct = 1
;
```

Output:

```
TYPE ITEM SECTION
---- ---- -------
CT2  A    M-2
CT1  A    M-2
CT2  A    M-3
CT1  B    M-1
CT2  B    M-1
CT2  B    M-2
CT1  B    M-2

7 rows selected.
```